# How to implement cURL on these parameters

Tags: php, curl

please I need your help.

I am working on a plagiarism api from Prepostseo, and I have been given this parameters to invoke using cURL. Now, I know little of cURL because I have been using file_get_contents. But now I am required to only use cURL. I have searched through their documentation, no reference material or source code available, not even on Github.

Here are the parameters, I need help please, on how to implement this:

```
curl -X POST https://www.prepostseo.com/apis/checkSentence \ 
-d "key=YOUR_KEY" 
-d "query=Inside that cage there was a green teddy bear"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, you can use the `https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php`

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.prepostseo.com/apis/checkSentence");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "key=YOUR_KEY&query=Inside that cage there was a green teddy bear");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) explains everything you need to know about how to use cURL in PHP.

The code snippet below will `POST` through a URL-encoded query string to the specified URL.

When the cURL call is performed, the response is assigned to the `$respsonse` variable, and the cURL call is closed there after.

```
$payload = [
  'key' => 'YOUR_KEY',
  'query' = 'Inside that cage there was a green teddy bear'
];    

$url = "https://www.prepostseo.com/apis/checkSentence";

//set up cURL - below is a general basic set up
$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

//specify your method
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

//for the body values you wish to POST through
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($payload)); 

//specifiy any specific headers you need here in your array
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, []);

//execute and close cURL
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```